# Unity - How to draw the orbit trajectory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

A few days ago I watched a video called "Coding Adventures: Solar System" which was made by Sebastian Lague. It inspired me to make my own simple simulation of the Solar System. Everything was fine until I needed to draw the orbit trajectory to set my Initial Velocity properly. I was searching and searching and didn't find anything. So here's my question. How can I draw an orbit trajectory in Unity?

Comment: There's plenty of answers in the Unity Q/A board.  Just Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script he uses for the trajectory is in the Debug folder: https://github.com/SebLague/Solar-System/blob/Episode_01/Assets/Scripts/Debug/OrbitDebugDisplay.cs
He basically create a new fake CelestialBody for each planet and calculate every position. He uses both [DrawLine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) and [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html).

Answer (score 1):

I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQKGRoV_jBc it is very well explained. It has a collection of videos to do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: That's good video, but it only shows how to make the planet follow the ellipse. My planets are using Newton's gravity equation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`LineRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html). It allows you to mark points along the object's trajectory given your ellipse equation, and it will create a corresponding line.